# IE alters JS Code before execution

Tags: javascript, iphone, internet-explorer, malformed

Why does IE & Iphones alter my JS-Source-Code?

I've got a minified JS File on my Server

```
... code A ...
... s < i ? ...
... do things ...
...  t[i] > 10 ...
... code B ...
```

Now the problem:
in IE and on Iphones the code gets trimmed in a strage way

```
... code A ....
... s10 ...
... code B ...
```

On Chrome, FF and Edge everything works fine.
Even in the response, which i can view via the networktab in IE, it is correct.
Just the executed code, which is also displayed when i request the file directly, is wrong.

Why does this happen?
How can i fix it?

**EDIT:**
I've found a workaround, that fixes this problem but is not a real solution:
just add some extra brackets

```
... (t[i] > (10)) ...
```

i don't know why but it does the job

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are running code that is not compatible in the version of IE you are testing

You should use [JSHint](http://JSHint) to check your code, set the option "esversion" to 3. This will check the compatibility of your code to ECMAScript 3.

Comment: Thanks for the tip,

i've checked the code with JSHint, and there are no errors, just a few warnings